# When to use "Component.WrappedComponent" when writing enzyme tests

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to use `shallow` rendering from enzyme by following the below pattern which works for many other components in my project.

```
describe('>> MyComponent - Render', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent.WrappedComponent
      actions={{}}
      history={}
    />);
  });

  it("test something", () => { expect(wrapper).toEqual(1); });

});
```

**What's the problem I have:**

I got an error saying "*Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined*", which means `wrapper` is `undefined`. But when I change `<MyComponent.WrappedComponent />` to just `<MyComponent />`, the tests are successful. This is my code:

```
describe('>> Legends - render', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Legends textsAndColor={[]} />);
  });

  it('+++ render the component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('+++ match snapshot', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**Question I have**:

What exactly does `.WrappedComponent` do ? And why does `<MyComponent />` works but not `<MyComponent.WrappedComponent />` ?

Comment: It appears that `WrappedComponent` is not a feature of enzyme, but rather a feature of certain React HOC components. For example, `react-router` implements this feature for its `withRouter` component: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#componentwrappedcomponent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using `.WrappedComponent` you are getting access to component, wrapped by redux's `connect` function.
I assume that most of your components are `connect`ed (since there are no problems with use of `.WrappedComponent`) and  component that throwing described error isn't `connect`ed.

I suggest you to read [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) to find out how to write tests for this case. Briefly said they suggest to have default export for your `connect`ed component and non-default for raw component. And then import only raw component for testing purposes, like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from './path/to/my/component`;
```

after this you will be able to `mount` (or `shallow`) your raw component like this:

```
describe('>> MyComponent - Render', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  }
});
```